Outer join entire date table with aggregate on business table
I'm trying to create a record for each person and year, where there may be a year where the person doesn't exist. I've used cross join in the past, but I think the aggregate here might be messing with a previous approach.
The goal is one record per person/year combination, for all years 2021-2024, and a count of those records when the person exists. Any help appreciated!
with person as 
(
    select 2021 as cov_year, 'A' as person 
    union all
    select 2021, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2022, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2024, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2024, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2024, 'A'
),
all_years as 
(
    select 2021 as year 
    union all
    select 2022 as year 
    union all
    select 2023 as year 
    union all   
    select 2024 as year
)
select 
    y.year, p.person, count(p.person) as ct 
from 
    all_years y 
left join 
    person p on y.year = p.cov_year
group by 
    y.year, p.person
order by 
    y.year;

Desired output:
year    person  ct
------------------
2021    A       2
2022    A       1
2023    A       (0 or null)
2024    A       3

Thanks!

on line 3 of desired there would not be any person A - the value would be null.
you can do COALESCE(p.Person, 'A'), or can do case when count(P.Person) = 0 - set A

i setup fillde db for you https://dbfiddle.uk/jQEDbbbW

@PowerMouse thank you, but the value 'A' in my sample data isn't clear I suppose.  The literal value 'A' doesn't work.  There are millions of records so imagine that there are person records for person B, C, D, etc.

If you want result rows for all persons in all years then you'll to use a cross join between distinct person and year:
with person as 
(
    select 2021 as cov_year, 'A' as person 
    union all
    select 2021, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2022, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2024, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2024, 'A' 
    union all
    select 2024, 'A'
),
all_persons as
(
  select distinct person from person
),
all_years as 
(
    select 2021 as year 
    union all
    select 2022 as year 
    union all
    select 2023 as year 
    union all   
    select 2024 as year
)
select 
    y.year, ap.person, count(p.person) as ct 
from 
    all_years y
cross join
    all_persons ap
left join 
    person p on p.person = ap.person and y.year = p.cov_year
group by 
    y.year, ap.person
order by 
    y.year;

dbfiddle.

I was really hoping to avoid a distinct, but this definitely works.  There are tens of millions of records in the actual person table.  But I'll see how it shakes out.  Thank you @HABO.

Well, that changes the question. An index on person can still help with distinct since an index scan can be faster than a table scan. For a really fast solution see this answer which uses a view with an index to maintain the distinct values.
